# CSS / Add margin-top to embedded facebook post

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML/CSS/JS website where I'm embedding facebook posts, and adding some text (with various info and action buttons) to the top of each post. I'm adding the text that goes above each post dynamically in Javascript, so that the embedded post (iframe) is in a separate container than the text that goes above it.

As you can see in the image below, the text is positioned as `absolute` so that it appears above the post, and not next to it. However, I can't seem to get the post to move *down* nor the text to move up in order to create some separation between them. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

UPDATE: I meant to include a codepen that reproduces the issue with minimal code: https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/dyLzLNV?editors=1111

See below for code as well:

```js
// Array of facebook post ID's
facebookArr = [{
    post_id: "pfbid0cm7x6wS3jCgFK5hdFadprTDMqx1oYr6m1o8CC93AxoE1Z3Fjodpmri7y2Qf1VgURl"
  },
  {
    post_id: "pfbid0azgTbbrM5bTYFEzVAjkVoa4vwc5Fr3Ewt8ej8LVS1hMzPquktzQFFXfUrFedLyTql"
  }
];

// Variables to store post ID, embed code, parent container
let postId = "";
let embedCode = "";
let facebookContainer = document.getElementById("facebook-feed-container");
$(facebookContainer).empty();

// Loop through data to display posts
facebookArr.forEach((post) => {
  let relativeContainer = document.createElement("div");

  postId = post.post_id;

  postLink = `${postId}/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading`;

  // ---> UPDATE: separate container element
  let iframeContainer = document.createElement("div");


  embedCode = `<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FIconicCool%2Fposts%2F${postId}&show_text=true&width=500" width="200" height="389" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" id=fb-post__${postId}></iframe>`;

  // Update the DOM
  iframeContainer.innerHTML = embedCode;

  // ADDITIONAL TEXT
  let additionalText = document.createElement("div");

  additionalText.className = "absolute";
  additionalText.innerText = "additional text to append";

  relativeContainer.append(additionalText, iframeContainer);
  facebookContainer.append(relativeContainer);
});
```

```css
#facebook-feed-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  color: red;
}

.risk-container {
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="facebook-feed-container">

</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D totally - ugh- 4am here and I forgot to include a link to code. I'll add the snippet and here's a codepen as well https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/dyLzLNV?editors=1111

Comment: Why not add the text to the div that holds the iFrame?

Comment: Good point! Ok, I updated my code with that change...I'm still not seeing a way to get the text **above** the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not injecting the text in the iframe actually, so it is simpler to define a component that will embed both the additionnal text and the facebook post.

Simplified version of your snippet below:

```js
facebookArr = [
  {
    post_id:
      "pfbid0cm7x6wS3jCgFK5hdFadprTDMqx1oYr6m1o8CC93AxoE1Z3Fjodpmri7y2Qf1VgURl"
  },
  {
    post_id:
      "pfbid0azgTbbrM5bTYFEzVAjkVoa4vwc5Fr3Ewt8ej8LVS1hMzPquktzQFFXfUrFedLyTql"
  }
];

let facebookContainer = document.getElementById("facebook-feed-container");

facebookArr.forEach((post) => {
  const postId = post.post_id;
  
  const postContainer = document.createElement("div");
  facebookContainer.append(postContainer);
  postContainer.classList.add('post');

  const postTitle = document.createElement("div");
  postContainer.append(postTitle)
  postTitle.classList.add('post--title');
  postTitle.innerHTML = "additional text to append"
  
  const postFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  postContainer.append(postFrame)
  postFrame.classList.add('post--frame');
  postFrame.id= `fb-post__${postId}`
  postFrame.src = `https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FIconicCool%2Fposts%2F${postId}&show_text=true&width=500`
  postFrame.width = "200"
  postFrame.height = "389"
  postFrame.scrolling = "no"
  postFrame.frameborder = "0"
  postFrame.allowfullscreen = "true"
  postFrame.allow = "autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"  
});
```

```css
#facebook-feed-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.post--title {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.post--frame {
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook-feed-container"></div>
```